# Fixing a CSS problem for my JavaScript powered nav menu

Tags: javascript, css

Hey, I have a JavaScript powered navigation bar used for the primary navigation on my website, www.marioplanet.com.

I am having some trouble when I try to adjust the width of my nav bar to be flush with the rest of my page, and it appears to throw the height off for some reason.

Any suggestions would be helpful and greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that "Privacy Policy" created a wrap. In your `ul, li` style declaration, add `white-space: nowrap;`. Then it's just for you to play with the width in the `#nav li` style declaration. `224px` seem to work in Firefox.

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you so much!  What was the wrapper though in Privacy Policy?

Comment: Actually, just wondering, it appears as though the text in the nav bar got a little off center, and idea how to fix?

Comment: No problem. It appears that the padding in `#nav li a` needs to be adjusted since the `li` is now wider than it used to be.

Comment: That's what I was messing with actually, I can't seem to get a value that is just right.. Any ideas as to what values are best?

Comment: It seems the LI has to be 224px with text-align: center; and the anchors need to be 224px as well. You'll need to play around with these to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

```
#nav {width:1130px; }
```

should fix your width without adversely changing the height.
(checked in FF, Chrome 5 and IE 7+8)